# Period of exponential must be purely imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis

In Ahlfors' Complex Analysis, p. 45, he's deriving the periodicity of the complex exponential (defined through a power series) and after noting the multiplicative property ($e^{z+u}  = e^z e^u$), he uses that to derive that if $e^{z+c} = e^z$, then $e^c = 1$. He then says "it follows that $c= i \omega$ with real $\omega$". Where does this come from?

Answer (score 2):

Write $c = x + iy$. Then $1 = e^c = \overline{e^c} = e^{\overline c}$, so $1 = 1 \cdot 1 = e^c e^c = e^c e^{\overline c} = e^{c + \overline c} = e^{2x}$.

Then $x \in \mathbb R$. Since $e^x = \sum_j \frac{x^j}{j!}$, $e$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$, so $e$ is injective. Then noting $e^0 = 1$, we get that $e^{2x} = 1$ implies $2x = 0$, hence $x = 0$. Thus $c = iy$ for some real $y$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^c=1.$$

Let $c=a+ib$ (where $a$ and $b$ are both real).

$$e^ae^{ib}=1$$

$$|e^a e^{ib}|=e^a=1 \Rightarrow a=0 \text{ and } c=ib.$$